# JavaScript variable hoisting explanation

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I came across the following article about variable hoisting in javascript. The article sums up the following three points.

```
1. All declarations, both functions and variables, are hoisted to the top of the containing scope, before any part of your code is executed.
2. Functions are hoisted first, and then variables.
3. Function declarations have priority over variable declarations, but not over variable assignments.
```

[Site Point](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

```
var showState = function() {
  console.log("Idle");
};

function showState() {
  console.log("Ready");
} 

showState();
```

I understood that the code is interpreted by the javascript engine as

```
function showState() { // moved to the top (function declaration)
    console.log("Ready");
}

var showState; // moved to the top (variable declaration)
showState = function() { // left in place (variable assignment)
    console.log("Idle");
};

showState();
```

But, I couldn't get the meaning of the third point in the summary. Can anyone care to explain the third point? What is the meaning of the third point?

According to the explanation of the third point, the following snippet should return 8, function bar(). But it says undefined, function bar().

```
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
var foo = 8;
function bar() {
    console.log("bar");
}
```

Comment: In your case, the point #3 would mean that the variable assignment statement `var foo` would be hoisted BEFORE your `function bar()` gets hoisted. so in reality your interpreted code would be `var foo; function bar()` if you didn't have assignment statement, it would have been `function bar(); var foo`

Comment: Isn't `foo = 8;` the variable assignment and `var foo;` the variable declaration part?

Comment: Can you explain why is it so? For functions to have precedence there is a meaning I think, as they might be used.

Comment: @AdityaParab Does it mean that it is applicable for the function expressions as well? As it also has assignment.

Comment: I am not sure why this rule is implemented by the JS engines. I am just making a wild guess based on my experience developing js code. In a neatly maintainable code, the developers are encouraged to expose methods to outside world - not the variables. And since it's the methods we are exposing we can not afford to get `undefined` outside. :) I sincerely believe this is the reason behind why functions take priority over uninitialized variables.

Comment: In case where variables are initialized, it is a sign that this variable controls some behavior in the code that follows, therefore, the initialized variables must take precedence over functions for those functions `may` required this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the article you link to:

> In the code above we saw that the function declaration takes
>   precedence over the variable declaration. And in the next example
>   we’ll see that when we have function declaration versus variable
>   assignment, the last takes priority.
>
> ```
> var showState = function() {
>   console.log("Idle");
> };
>
> function showState() {
>   console.log("Ready");
> } 
>
> showState();            // output: Idle
> ```

A function declaration does two things:

1. It declares a variable with the same name as the function
2. It assigns the function to that variable

Both of these are hoisted, not just the variable declaration. (This is unlike `var` statements with an associated assignment where only the declaration is hoisted).

This means that despite the `= function() {` code being first, the *later* function declaration still runs first so `= function() {` can overwrite it.

Comment: @Quentin var showState;

showState = function() {
 console.log("ready");
};

showState = function() {
 console.log("Idle");
};

showState();

Is this what has happended internally?

Comment: @BRS — Since there are other differences between function expressions and function declarations: not really.

Comment: @Quentin Is the following correct understanding for function expressions? var showState;

function showState() {
  console.log("Ready");
} 

showState = function() {
 console.log("Idle");
};

showState();    and for variable assignments the following var foo;
function bar() {
    console.log("bar");
}
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
foo = 8;

Comment: @BRS No, the correct interpretation is `function showState(){console.log("Ready");}; var showState; showState = function(){console.log("Idle");}; showState();`

Comment: @BRS In this case variable `showState` is getting overridden by that assignment.

Comment: @abforce I am extremely sorry for the lack of understanding. But where does the precedence of the assignment take place?

Comment: @BRS — That question doesn't really made sense as an English sentence.

Comment: @Quentin :) Thanks. Corrected the comment.

Comment: @Quentin Can you edit your answer with what happens internally with the example I mentioned in the question(last example)?

Comment: @BRS — The third point in the summary doesn't actually have anything to do with that code. It only matters when you assign a value to the variable with the same name as a function declaration. abforce's answer already shows what happens in that code.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks a lot. Now I am clear. So the snippet foo = 8 has nothing to do with the 3rd point. It is applicable only to function with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Your last example is interpreted as

```
function bar() {
    console.log("bar");
}    
var foo;

console.log(foo); // here 'foo' is undefined
console.log(bar); // bar is of type function
foo = 8;
```

Comment: It  should have been the following right? As the assignment takes precedence?                                                                                        var foo;
function bar() {
    console.log("bar");
}    

console.log(foo); 
console.log(bar); 
foo = 8;

Comment: No, function `bar` is declared _first_ then `foo` is declared.

Comment: :) Then what is the point of third statement in the summary of the article? Is it incorrect?

Comment: Care to check the first comment of the question by Aditya? Thanks.

Comment: @BRS No it's correct. User [Quentin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) has explained why.

Comment: Thanks. But still I have the same question. If the third point is correct then the comment of Aditya should be correct.

Comment: In my opinion that comment is incorrect and that third point is correct. Find the why in Quentin's answer.

Comment: Aditya's comment is irrelevant. The order in which two variables are declared doesn't matter since they don't interact with each other until after they are declared, and the third point is talking about assignments.

Answer (score -1):

Basically - lets say we have, in no particular order

```
function hello(){};
var sup;
var yo = 4;
```

with variable hoisting the order would become

```
    var yo = 4;
    function hello(){};
    var sup;
```

because the var assignment has priority over the function, which has priority over the function declaration.

Comment: console.log(typeof hello);
    console.log(typeof yo);
    console.log(typeof sup);
    function hello() {}
    var yo = 4;
    var sup;   produces function, undefined, undefined. But according to you second one should be a number right?